# How can I run a linux command with brackes in Github workflow YAML?

Tags: github, github-actions

In a github workflow YAML, I've been trying several ways to run a command to remove all the content of a directory excluding a directory, and I don't find the way to make it work.

The command is:
`rm -rf !(dist)`

It throws an error since brackets are special yaml characters, so I have to quote them `rm -rf "!(dist)"`. Then Github workflow doesn't throw any error, but the command isn't working.

Some idea how can I make it work?

To give more context, I want to publish just the `dist` content of a NPM project, instead publishing the root of it including the `dist` folder.

This is the YAML:

```
name: Node.js Package

on:
  release:
    types: [created]

jobs:
  publish-gpr:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions: write-all
  steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
    with:
      node-version: 16
    - run: npm ci
    - run: npm run build
    - run: |
        rm -rf "!(dist)"
        cd dist
        cp -R ./ ../
        cd ..
        rm -rf ./dist
    - run: npm publish
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The default shell on `ubuntu-latest` is Bash. See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsshell. And, you have to run `shopt -s extglob` to enable that syntax. See https://superuser.com/a/193836/863926.

Comment: Your pasted workflow is invalid. Use https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/ and fix those issues.

Comment: Regarding "It throws an error since brackets are special yaml characters, so I have to quote them rm -rf "!(dist)". Then Github workflow doesn't throw any error, but the command isn't working.", that's valid YAML. The command itself is under multiline syntax. That should throw any error at all. That issue must be something else.

Comment: See [here](https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/#eJxtkMFOwzAQRO/5iuEGBztCSBx84gsQ6hVxcJylcevYltduhcTHY7chRBW38c7s2117PZPCaxhJHhhv2hz1nroueNUBiRxppiaB/BWJFd5NIp1p/Oi6Qxi4ebEMzvIk9jFdo6l4FhWBMhSfi3C1gfPFipRmy2yDr6xzspmEdu5icabIV4BA4TZMm9ySvZnIHEPJL6enf32mXKLw9YrfBHC2eVKLBponTpTaZIXH5wVTN1XwcYaxt5UqMBTrxq3xvQLTDJE+cXc/Ws4Pa9mMaIW/d4TYQfaQst+GpLwlyX5t3Gyx/O0PoX53rg==).

Comment: @Azeem the YAML I wrote here is wrong, you are right, it is missing some spaces, but that's not the problem. The problem are the brackets. The yaml works perfectly in github, it is just a wrong indentation here in the question.

Comment: @Azeem certainly, adding `shopt -s extglob` to the beggining it works with brackets! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Azeem indicated in the comments, I had to add `shopt -s extglob` to the beggining of the script.

This is the working YAML with brackets:

```
name: Node.js Package

on:
  release:
    types: [created]

jobs:
  publish-gpr:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions: write-all
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16
      - run: npm ci
      - run: npm run build
      - run: |
          shopt -s extglob
          rm -rf "!(dist)"
          cd dist
          cp -R ./ ../
          cd ..
          rm -rf ./dist
      - run: npm publish
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you can get around this is use find instead of rm -rf. I believe this is the syntax or close to it:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -name dist -prune -o -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

if that does not work try this:

```
find -maxdepth 1 ! -name dist ! -name . -exec rm -rf {} \;
```